# Access random items from an array in the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk

I want to know how to access random items from array in the iPhone SDK?

I have made a music player in which the next song comes from array on button-click, but I want to get the songs randomly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the *rand()* function:

```
NSInteger randomIndex = rand () % [list count];
Thing * randomThing = [list objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
```

Don't forget to call *srand(unsigned int seed)* on startup:

```
srand(time(0));
```

Comment: @pankaj No problem :) If this answers your question, you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick on the left.

Comment: @RedBlueThing why the srand(time(0); and where exactly to call it?

Comment: @MasterRazer srand(time(0)) seeds the random number generator with the time so you get a psuedo random value when you call rand (). Just stick it in your AppDelegate didFinish ...