# Get random object from Array

Tags: iphone, arc4random

I want to get random object from array, is there any way how can I find random object from mutable array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access randon items from an array in i phone sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509411/how-to-access-randon-items-from-an-array-in-i-phone-sdk)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
@interface NSArray (Random)
- (id) randomObject;
@end

@implementation NSArray (Random)

- (id) randomObject
{
     if ([self count] == 0) {
         return nil;
     }
     return [self objectAtIndex: arc4random() % [self count]];
}

@end
```

Comment: To avoid modulo bias, rather than arc4random() use arc4random_uniform(). (For more, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator).

Answer (score 8):

```
id obj;    
int r = arc4random() % [yourArray count];
    if(r<[yourArray count])
      obj=[yourArray objectAtIndex:r];
   else
   {
     //error message
   }
```

Comment: @Thilo,In else case any message or whatever required.

Answer (score 7):

```
id randomObject = nil;
if ([array count] > 0){
    int randomIndex = arc4random()%[array count];
    randomObject = [array objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to do something like this

```
int length = [myMutableArray count];
// Get random value between 0 and 99
int randomindex = arc4random() % length;

Object randomObj = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:randomindex];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just Copy and Paste**

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getRandomValueFromArray:(NSMutableArray*)arrAllData randomDataCount:(NSInteger)count {  
 NSMutableArray *arrFilterData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0; i<count; i++){

     NSInteger index = arc4random() % (NSUInteger)(arrAllData.count);
    [arrFilterData addObject:[arrAllData objectAtIndex:index]];
    [arrAllData removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
return arrFilterData;
}
```

Note: Count = number of random values you want to fetch

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **Swift solution** using an extension on Arrays:

```
extension Array {
    func sample() -> Element? {
        if self.isEmpty { return nil }
        let randomInt = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))
        let randomIndex = self.startIndex.advancedBy(randomInt)
        return self[randomIndex]
    }
}
```

You can use it **as simple as this**:

```
let digits = Array(0...9)
digits.sample() // => 6
```

---

If you prefer a **Framework** that also has some more handy features then checkout **[HandySwift](https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandySwift)**. You can add it to your project **via Carthage** then use it exactly like in the example above:

```
import HandySwift    

let digits = Array(0...9)
digits.sample() // => 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to extend NSArray this will get a random value from a given array in one line:

```
id randomElement = [myArray objectAtIndex:(arc4random() % myArray.count)];
```