# Displaying randomly chosen text in a label from an array

Tags: ios, nsarray, uilabel

Working in Xcode. 
I can't quite figure this one out. What I'd like to do is have an array of strings "one", "two", "three" etc. 
I want to be able to have a label which displays one of these strings, chosen at random. Any ideas?

What I've tried so far is this:
I've created an array as such:

```
NSString *yes0 = @"yes";
NSString *yes1 = @"YES";
NSString *yes2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yes1];
NSArray *googleArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:yes0, yes1, yes2, nil];
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to display an element of this array randomly. I've figured out how to pass a variable to the label which would be as such:

```
strValue = @"";
yourLabel.text = strValue;
```

I'm guessing after I have randomly chosen an element from the array, I set strValue equal to that and hence it gets set as my label. I do not understand the random choosing of the string itself.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you've tried?

Comment: Obviously you didn't try anything, even searching in google, this is the first anserw you will find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580354/get-random-object-from-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 int randomNumber = arc4random() % [yourArray count];
 NSString *string = [yourArray objectAtIndex:randomNumber];
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! Accepting your answer as soon as it lets me!